# cling dlna media server example

Tags: upnp, dlna, cling

I want to create my own DLNA media server in JAVA (preferably using CLING, but any other stable library is fine as well). I've been searching for a good example, tutorial, training on how to do so, but was unable to find anything. Would anybody have a good/minimal source code example for a DLNA media server? I am new to DLNA. Trying to learn more on it, but technical details on the technology seem scares as well.

There is one more challenge I'm facing. I will be exposing content (mp3, mts, avi, mov, ...) already available via http. Creating the HTTP URL for this content however is an "expensive" operation (in terms of time, resource load) and the URLs are only valid for a limited time. Hence putting all URLs in a list at DLNA server time won't be an option. Ideally I should be able to hook somehow on a client of my DLNA server starting playback, create the URL then and pass it to the client.

All help is very much appreciated.

Regards,
Sven.

Comment: Did you figure out?